# SwiftUI Padding Not Working After Upgrading to iOS14 Beta 4 and Xcode 12 Beta 4

Tags: xcode, swiftui, padding, ios14, xcode12

I am currently updating my iOS application to support iOS 14, using Xcode Beta software. Yesterday, I updated to Xcode Beta 4 and padding on my application became all out of wack.

[image]

In the image above, I have the padding set to `.padding({.top,.bottom}, 4)`, which does not correlate to the output. Xcode is forcing the default padding for anything under 15 to actually be 15.

Before updating to Beta 4, the padding correctly set it to 4, I can't find anything anywhere on if this is new functionality/bugs/etc...

This also seems to only be occurring within my VStack. See below:

```
                    VStack
                    {
                        Text(latitudeToDMS())
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                            .font(.system(size: g.size.width / 25))
                            .foregroundColor(Color("baby-blue"))
                        
                        Text(getLaitudeValue())
                            .fontWeight(.medium)
                            .font(.system(size: g.size.width / 28))
                            .foregroundColor(Color("text"))
                    }
                    .padding([.leading,.trailing], 20)
                    .padding([.top,.bottom], 10)
                    .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15).fill(Color("background")))
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15))
                    .shadow(color: Color("neumorphic"), radius: 4, x: 1,  y: 1)
```

If I add `.padding(.bottom, 4)` under the baby-blue foreground color, I get the same results as the image that is presented above.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Unsure, but I also noticed my padding in views was all funky now going from iOS 13 to 14.

Comment: Yeh, seems like default padding values have broken in iOS 14 